# RMI exportObject(Remote obj, PORT); createRegistry(PORT);

Tags: java, rmi

I'm wondering can both the

```
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote,portNo) & LocateRegistry.createRegistry(portNo);
```

porNo be the same?

I test it works but I'm worrid if there is any complication?

Why does exportObject need to specify an object to work? when I use exportObject(Remote obj) it throws an `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering can both the
>
> ```
> UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote,portNo) &
> LocateRegistry.createRegistry(portNo);
> ```
>
> portNo be the same?

Yes, unless you are using unequal socket factories, which you aren't. If there is a problem an exception will be thrown.

> I test it works but I'm worrid if there is any complication?

Not at all, in fact it's a good idea, saves on listening ports. You can use Registry.REGISTRY_PORT which is reserved at IANA, and should therefore shut down any arguments with netadmins too.

> Why does exportObject need to specify an object to work?

Because it is a static method.

> when I use exportObject(Remote obj) it throws an
>   StubNotFoundException.

Because you haven't generated a stub. If you are using >= 1.5, you don't need a generated stub, but you do need to specify a port number. If you specify zero you will get a system-allocated port number but if you have already exported a remote object, in this case the Registry, you will share its port, again unless you are using unequal socket factories.

Comment: care to define unequal socket factories? Sorry kind of new with this socket and RMI. I'm using 1.6, I get NullPointException.

Comment: @seesee a NullPointerException means something has not been initialized. I would suggest debugging that code and trying to figure out what variable was left uninitialized.

Comment: @seesee unequal socket factories are socket factories for which sf1.equals(sf2) returns false, as everywhere else in Java.