# How to access JMX (Java Beans) from a process running in docker container

Tags: java, docker, jmx

Why is it so hard to connect to a JMX port (using JConsole), when a process is run using Docker.

Of course I have **exposed the JMX port to the host**, and even used **Sun specific options** while running the Java process (following the instructions from http://ptmccarthy.github.io/2014/07/24/remote-jmx-with-docker/ ).

I am able to telnet to the host ip and the exposed JMX port, which tells that it is accessible. But I can't figure out a way to use JConsole and connect to the JMX service running in the container.

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$JMX_HOSTNAME
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT
```

Comment: i assume that JMX_HOSTNAME is the externally visible hostname?

Comment: Also, you are using at least jre/jdk 7+, right?

Comment: @jtahlborn yes.. I am using JDK 8 and yes JMX_HOSTNAME is externally visible

Comment: Here is a smaple app with good description https://github.com/cstroe/java-jmx-in-docker-sample-app

Answer (score 0):

In the past, the two ports had to be different. Please try that for a start.

If thats not working:

Tomcat offers an additional component to set the second port mentioned, the **JMX Remote Lifecycle Listener**.

Please have a look at:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/extras.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

I´m using this setting with catalina-jmx-remote.jar in my tomcat/lib directory to get through:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-DrmiRegistryPortPlatform=10381 
-DrmiServerPortPlatform=10380
```

Plus these, but you wouldn´t need them in a dev environment.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/home/tomcat/jmxremote.password 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/home/tomcat/jmxremote.access 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
```

Comment: Hey Christian
Just wanted to say, I am not using Tomcat.. its a Core-Java application running few Managed Beans. Does  these settings still apply?

Comment: The settings are tomcat specific, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have looks correct.  To at least try and get it working, i'd try disabling auth & ssl.  Then, once you get it working, think about re-enabling any security you require:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: @Sohail - ah, i didn't see those details in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, you need those 2 ports to be different. One port is for the RMI registry and the other for the remoting protocol.

When specifying the URL to connect to the server from jconsole/visualvm use the port set in "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port" on the server side.

Comment: Nope, the two ports can be the same, and it's even better for them to be the same if behind a firewall (should be the default behavior).

Comment: No, it's not the default behavior. When you don't specify the rmiport it is chosen from the transient range randomly.

As I said - one port is for the RMI registry and the second one for the actual remoting wire protocol. I really can't see how those 2 services might share the same  port.

Comment: yes, i realize it's not the default behavior, i was making an editorial comment that i think it _should_ be the default behavior.

Comment: Here's some details for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366240/implications-of-restricting-rmi-to-one-port